Numeraire flipping and currency FX options
In Dynamic Hedging by N. Taleb at pag. 435 is stated that:

Numeraire flipping consists of switching the unit in which the numeraire is expressed from base currency to counterasset. Thus, a call on S with strike K, risk neutral rate rd and counterasset rate d can be priced as a put on 1/S with strike 1/K, risk neutral rate d and counterasset rate rd.

Since I can't obtain the price of a call as stated in the "numerarie flipping principle", I am not able to figurate out by myself the 3 critical points reported below. Could someone explain to me, with some math if possible, what is happening?
Please, let me know if more details are needed. Thanks for the help.
Edit
B&S formula:
If I understand right, I should get the same price by calculating, assuming zero rates for the domestic and foreign rates:
$$Call(S,K,T) = SN(d1)-KN(d2)=\frac1KN(-d2')-\frac1SN(-d1')=Put(\frac1S,\frac1K,T)$$
Example: S=5 USD-EUR (1 USD = 5 EUR), K=5.6 USD-EUR, TTM=180, vol=15.7%. I get call=0.0460 and put=0.0016
The call is priced in EUR so I should divide by 5, the spot rate? I get call=0.0092. Still different.
What am I missing? Am I violating something by taking zero interest rates?
Edit 2
This part is moved to another more specific question. I keep it also there since there is some comments about it and is related to the flipping principle.
From this principle the author in the book highlights some critical points:

The delta of the call and put obtained through this principle will be different (p. 435)
A bet in dollars for a dollar based person on USD-DEM is different in price from the translation into German marks of a bet in German marks on USD-DEM of the same strike and expiration (p. 286).
The price of a bet for a dollar-based person, which is N(d2), is different from the price of the bet for the person based in DEM (for example) as this latter will be N(d1) (p. 286).


Intuitively, buying a call on the SPX500 (struck at 1000, for argument's sake) means that we have an option to buy the SPX in exchange for 1000 USD. This can be seen as having the option to sell 1000 USD in exchange for one unit of SPX: thereby having a put option on the USD, denominated in SPX. With currencies, it's the same thing: owning a call struck at 1.1 on EUR/USD means an option to buy 1 unit of EUR for 1.1 USD. This can be seen as having a put option on USD struck at $\frac{1}{1.1}$ EUR.

@JanStuller: thanks, I understand what are you saying. My problem is that, if I am right, when I put these numbers in the Black&Scholes formulas for put and call I do not obtain the same price. I'm adding an Edit on my OP.

The numbers will not be the same, because the EUR/USD call option is denominated in USD whilst the USD/EUR put will be denominated in EUR. If you take the spot exchange rate into account, you should get the same result. Also the risk-free rate $r$ will be different: for the call, you need to use the prevailing USD rate, for the put, you need to use the prevailing EUR rate.

I've just added an example with the convention of currency quotes used in the book, sligthly different. I appreciate the help.

There are two interest rates in the BSM formula: the interest rate on cash $r_f$ and the dividend rate on the SP500 $q$ (or the foreign interest rate in the case of FX options). Make sure you "flip" the two rates around when you "flip" the BSM formula. The domestic and foreign rates switch places.

@nbbo2: thanks for the help. In the example I added in the Edit section I am assuming zero interest rates. Does it cause problems? It's a toy example just to understand the basics of this "flippling principle".

For the three principles: I think 2 and 3 are a slightly different setup — looks like it might be binary options and/or a bet on currency hitting a certain level but paying off in different currencies if it does. For 1, I’d loosely say that one option is driven by $x$ and the other is driven by $1/x$ which ofc have different derivatives — you can extend this thinking to be as formal as you like if it helps.

I can confirm that they are binary bets. I was asking for the formulas to understand the 3 points. If you want to complete the answer then I will accept it!

Who downvoted the question? I do not see problems in how it is posed otherwise I would like to receive constructive suggestions.

https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/63552/54838

@AKdemy thanks, the examples in your answer helped me in applying what Rylan showed me mathematically.

Looking at the example above after the edits. The short answer is you need to multiply by $K$ as well as the FX rate.
For the longer answer:
Lets let $D^e, D^u$ be the discount processes in the different currencies. Like your example, S(t) refers to the price in EUR of one USD. Let's
We consider the EUR-denominated call on one USD $C(t)$. I'll calculate it at time $t=0$ to make the notation a bit lighter.
$$C(0) = \mathbb{E}^e(D^e(T)(S(T) - K)^+)$$
"multiplying by one" strategically, this gives
$$C(0) = \mathbb{E}^e\Big(D^e(T)\frac{D^u(T)}{D^u(T)}(S(T) - K)^+\Big)$$
Factoring out $S(T)$ from the positive part expression we get
$$C(t) = \mathbb{E}^e\Bigg(D^e(T)\frac{D^u(T)}{D^u(T)}S(T)\Big(1 - \frac{K}{S(T)}\Big)^+\Bigg)$$
Note that $\frac{S(t)D^u(t)}{D^e(t)}$ is an $e-$martingale (an arbitrage argument ensures that the European market risk-neutral drift of $S(T)$ is the difference between the EUR and USD rates.), so we can use it to define a new measure, which we'll call the $u$ measure.
Again multiplying strategically by one, we get
$$C(0) = \frac{S(0)D^u(0)}{D^e(0)}\frac{\mathbb{E}^e\Bigg(D^u(T)\frac{S(T)D^e(T)}{D^u(T)}\Big(1 - \frac{K}{S(T)}\Big)^+\Bigg)}{\mathbb{E}^e\Big(\frac{S(T)D^u(T)}{D^e(T)}\Big)}$$
Changing the measure gives us:
$$C(0) = \frac{S(0)D^u(0)}{D^e(0)}\mathbb{E}^u\Bigg(D^u(T)\Big(1 - \frac{K}{S(T)}\Big)^+ \Bigg)$$
and factoring out the $K$ we get
$$C(0) = \frac{KS(0)D^u(0)}{D^e(0)}\mathbb{E}^u\Bigg(D^u(T)\Big(\frac{1}{K} - \frac{1}{S(T)}\Big)^+ \Bigg)$$
Which simplifies to
$$K \times S(0) \times \text{USD-denominated put}$$

Thank you, this is interesting and clear. Two questions: 1) what is the reason why the two discount rates disappear in the last equation? 2) It would be interesting to know why in the comments and in the book only one rate was needed to translate between prices. Well, you could complete the answer by looking at the three critical points since you seems quite proficient with the math involved ;)

One last question: could you indicate more explicitly what is the change of measure used? Thanks again.


In general for a discount factor $D(t)$, $D(0)$ is 1. (e.g. if your discount factor is $D(t) = e^{rt}$ then $D(0) = 0$. Your rates are 1 so it'd be zero anyway for any $t$



I think you've got two rates (r and rd) there -- I'm assuming he uses "counterasset rate" to apply to anything like a dividend, foreign risk free rate, whatever. For me I'm being a bit more explicit and stating directly that it's a foreign rate. (This book has been in my amazon cart for a while, maybe it's time for me to finally buy it...)



Wikipedia's description is decent if you have some experience with this stuff https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Num%C3%A9raire. If not I'd suggest looking at Shreve's Stochastic Calculus for Finance II, specifically section 9.3


For 2) I was referring to the fact only  one exchange rate was needed for the conversions whilst you showed that there is also the strike exchange rate involved. Thanks for the references, I will have a look at them. Regarding the book, there is a lot of interesting stuff but from time to time some steps are quite confounding, as my question page can testimony:)

If it helps, bringing K out to the front is sort of just an algebraic trick — we could have done it at any point. If you look at the second-to-last equation, we’re saying that it’s not so much an option with strike 1/K and asset 1/S, but an option on K units of 1/S with strike 1. Pulling out the strike is arguably easier and it makes stuff fit into a Black Scholes pricer more nicely, but it’s more of an algebra trick than an exchange rate with some economic interpretation
