How to calculate the FX ON and TN swap points
Here is from the BBG  page to calculate the FX ON and TN swap points,
my question is why it is to minus ask side points when calculate the bid side outright?
eg: ON bid outright: spot bid - TN ask points - ON ask points
Thanks.
BBG <HELP>
{LPHP FRD:0:1 2898067 }:
ON ("Overnight"), TN ("Tomorrow-Next"), and SN ("Spot-Next") are not tenors; they are swaps. Each are associated with two separate settlement dates, one for each leg:
• ON is the swap between TOD and TOM.
• TN is the swap between TOM and the following business day (which is spot in a T+2 currency).

{LPHP FRD:0:1 612124 }:
Certain rules apply when calculating two-day settlements for Overnight (ON) and Tomorrow Night (TN) outrights.
Two-Day Settlement Outright Calculations
• ON bid outright: spot bid - TN ask points - ON ask points
• ON ask outright: spot ask - TN bid points - ON bid points
• TN bid outright: spot bid - TN ask points
• TN ask outright: spot ask - TN bid points


This post may help https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/71303/understanding-fx-forward-points-and-market-usage/71306#71306

By convention time spreads are expressed as price at the later date minus price at the earlier date. You add the spread when you want to move forward in time. You are buying the spread. To move backwards in time (eg. from T+2 (spot) to T+1 (Tomorrow)) you have to subtract (hence the minus sign) the spread and swap the bid and ask. You are selling the spread.

Thanks @nbbo2. For spot bid=1, 1m swap point bid=0.0100, then 1m FWD bid=1.0100, we use the same direction. While TN swap point ask=0.0001, then TN Outright bid=1-0.0001. Why we changed the direction to move backwards on ON and TN, not for other tenors longer than spot? Thanks again

1m is forward from spot, tomorrow (i.e. T+1) is backwards from spot (i.e. T+2). Draw a time axis if it helps.

Part 1, i used the data from the post you suggested. Case Assumption,
Bank Quotation
EURUSD bid ask outright bid outright ask
ON 0.304 0.556 1.0439722 1.044603
TN 0.666 0.722 1.0440278 1.0446334
SP 1.0441 1.0447 1.0441 1.0447
Eg: Outright TN bid = SP bid - TN ask = 1.0441 - 0.722/10000 = 1.0440278

Part2, Above is totally clear for me, while, I am really confused about the bid-ask directions.
Here is my workout based on SP bid and Outright bid to calculate the TN ask,
TN -> SP
Client sell/buy EURUSD = Bank buy/sell EURUSD,  bank quote ask side price,

Part 3, near leg TN / T+1 Client buy EUR10k ag USD @   Bank xxx side 1.0440278
far leg SP / T+2 Client sell EUR10k ag USD @    Bank bid side 1.0441
TN swap point ask side   0.7220
Question 1 // is it client buy swap spread = client sell/buy EURUSD from TN to SP or SP to TN?
Question 2 // is it near leg =TN and far leg=SP?
Question 3 // per the near leg part, I have no way to use TN bid=1.0440278

Thanks again @nbbo2, i used the Excel format, but i could not show up it here, sorry about that

Or, in short, when you say "selling the spread", backward from T+2 to T+1, what is the near leg and far leg? and is it buy/sell EURUSD (eg EURUSD), near leg buy EURUSD, far leg sell EURUSD?
