# How does Bloomberg bootstrap CASH Instruments?

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, yield-curve, bloomberg, bootstrapping

Given the following datas :

[image]

If we do the bootstrap methodology for CASH Instrument we gotta :

Calculate the DF associated to the Market Quoted Rate (2.91157). For the 3M Fixing we have :
T = 0.26115.

So the DF for this Market Quoted Rate is :

[image]

Then we can deduct the ZC Rate :

[image]

Which obviously does not match the Zero Rate shown in SWPM : 2.94084%

However doing :

[image]

Am I missing something or is Bloomberg SWPM Curve wrong ?

Comment: If you ask the help desk they will probably be able to give you the formula they are using.

Comment: @assylias Sadly, they don't help much.. Quant exchange is my only hope.

Comment: Bloomberg help page for the ICVS function includes a paper named "Building the Bloomberg Interest Rate Curve – Definitions and Methodology." Did you check it?

Comment: @AKdemy I did, and following the white paper we can dress the equation 1(1+Continuous Rate *T) = exp(-ZC*T) So to get ZC rate we solve the equation. But this does not it on what is shown on the screen. 2.901% would be the right rate if I follow the white paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The displayed curve uses ACT/365 daycount with continuous compounding. The ZC is calculated by converting from simple discounting (ACT/360) to continuous compounding (ACT/365).

Hence, you can replicate the discount factor using the ZC rate displayed above:

`=EXP(-2.94084%*94/365)`

which gives 0.992455. As far as I remember this value is for display only and in the backend the curve will be stripped with the daycount that's applicable to your deal.

Comment: But the question is how do they have -2.94084% as ZC Rate. What's the calculation to retrieve this ? 94/365 or 0.26112 is close to be the same and still give me a Zero rate of 2.901%

Comment: you need to convert the rate properly: `=-LN(1/(1+2.91157/100*94/360))/(94/365)*100`

Comment: Man so my mistake was that i alway used the same T but in fact one is on a 360 base and the other one is 365 Base

Comment: I am facing the same kind of issue for the Futures Part of the curve. You can find the new question [there](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/71935/42110). Hope you can help me with it.

Comment: sorry mate don't have time at the minute

Comment: No worries, if you can have a look when you will be free it would really help me.