How is it true that options can be equivalently seen as being written on the spot or its future?
I was recently told that options with expiration $T$ written on an underlying asset $(S_t)_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ could also be seen as options on its future $(F_t)_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$. This makes totally sense to me as $S_T=F_T$. However at this point it remains a heuristic. Does anybody have a reference that states it rigorously and gives an explanation?

For a storable commodity we have $F_t=S_t \exp( r(T-t))$ derived via the so-called cash and carry arbitrage

Not sure how to make it more rigorous than already explained by @nbbo2. Perhaps just to add that since $F_T = S_T$ you could also just price the option using the process $dF_t = \sigma F_t dW_t$ which has no drift anymore. Furthermore, sometimes the asset itself is not tradable, only the futures. In this case you have to use the process for $F_t$ to price the option as $F_t$ is also your hedge instrument.

https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/63661/54838 shows it with computer code and an example.
