Isn't this formula wrong on FX options?
In Iain Clark's book on Foreign Exchange Option Pricing, he says that the price of a FX option is
$$\exp^{-r_d t}\left[FN(d_1) - KN(d_2) \right]$$
where $$F = S\exp^{(r_d - r_f)t}$$
But isn't this wrong, as it seems to not take into account the basis?

That's a valid objection, but as long as you get F from the forward market, rather than calculating it via the second formula, things will be allright. Since you can observe F the second formula is not really needed.

It's common to imply one rate, usually the least liquid (but generally a setting in pricing engines) to keep the model internally consistent and arb free. See for example https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/63661/54838.
