What pricing curve to use for different instruments?
When pricing derivatives, their price depends on some yield curve, which is used to discount future cash flows.
But there are many yield curves, dependent on what they're bootstrapped from. There's government curves, there's swap curves, there's ois curves, and now there's rfr curves.
How do I know what yield curve to use for what instrument? The instruments I have in mind are bonds, swaps, swaptions, equity options, fx forwards and fx options. For bonds and swaps, does the answer depend on if the bond/swap is a float type that itself is referencing libor versus rfr versus ois?
Somebody told me "use whatever rate you get on your margin".
This answer is only useful for trades where a margin is posted, but that's only really equity options. What about the other cases I mentioned?

Also https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/74304/54838, https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/76335/54838, https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/64132/54838, https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/70296/54838 and so forth. Bonds are anyhow price quoted. If you want to manually compute NPV from Cashflows you cannot use risk free rates alone because bonds aren't risk free. Everything else on your list is using RFR, except FX forwards which are quoted (see https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/76971/54838 and others). OIS and RFR is technically the same, see here

curious regarding your last line:
"This answer is only useful for trades where a margin is posted, but that's only really equity options. What about the other cases I mentioned?" most trades are now collateralised, where collateral is rewarded at RFR usually..
Eg - swaps are usually cleared via LCH/CME. Swaptions will be bilateral and will fall under UMR (or at least bilateral margin), same for FX and FX Options..
